# Split text [without \n or <br>] on visible line breaks with JS

Tags: javascript, split, line-breaks

I have a span with max-width and a long text without \n or < br>. Is it possible to get the positions of the automaticly generated line breaks via JS?

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam voluptua" within a small span breaks for example like this:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,*[break]*
consetetur sadipscing elitr,*[break]*
sed diam voluptua"

I need to split the lines on breaks or get the index of the "hidden line break"-characters.

https://jsfiddle.net/DerLangeVonTetris/x63Ldcez/

HTML:

```
<h1 class="multiline-headline">
    <span class="decoration-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam voluptua</span>
</h1>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
        spanLines = [];

    // do magic start

    spanLines.push(span.innerText.slice(0,27));
    spanLines.push(span.innerText.slice(28,56));
    spanLines.push(span.innerText.slice(57));

    // do magic end

    document.getElementsByClassName('preview')[0].innerText = JSON.stringify(spanLines);    

}(window));
```

RESULT:

```
["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,","consetetur sadipscing elitr,","sed diam voluptua"]
```

---

Why I need this:

https://jsfiddle.net/DerLangeVonTetris/xgbsvpdy/

The decoration-break Polyfill "decofill" works on Edge when I add < br>s. But on responsive views I get problems when I add the HTML line breaks hardcoded. Therefore I need to add them on clientside.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: It would be very hard to do this unless you had a monospaced font, but please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site - currently your question is too broad and therefore off topic

Comment: I added some information

Comment: Did you check my answer?? it works very fine, look at it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your question! it has a big challenge, and i like challenges!!

I'm going to use my own trick for answering this question (via `pure js` and for the first time - without the same):

```js
function MyOwnSplit(myTextDiv){
  var res = myTextDiv.innerHTML.trim().split(/ +/).map(function(t){
    return "<span>"+t+" </span>";
  });
  var mainText = myTextDiv.innerHTML;
  var fakeDiv=document.createElement("div");
  fakeDiv.innerHTML=res.join("");
  fakeDiv.setAttribute("style", myTextDiv.getAttribute("style"));
  fakeDiv.style.visibility='hidden';
  myTextDiv.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", fakeDiv);
  var finalRes={}, l=0, prvCTop=-Infinity;
  fakeDiv.childNodes.forEach(function(c){
    var top = c.offsetTop, A;
    if(top!=prvCTop) {
      l+=1;
      finalRes[l]=(A=[]);
      prvCTop=top;
    } else A=finalRes[l];
    A.push(c.innerHTML.trim());
  });
  fakeDiv.parentElement.removeChild(fakeDiv);
  return finalRes;
}
var res=MyOwnSplit(document.querySelector(".my-text"));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
//or getting all lines:
var r={};
for(var lN in res) {r["Line"+lN]=res[lN].join(" ");};
console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

```html
<div style='width: 110px; border: solid 1px #f0f0f0' class='my-text'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam voluptua
</div>
<b>You can change the "width" and see the result.</b>
```

- The result1 is a object which per key is number of related line & value is words of that line.
- The result2 is a object which per key is line number & value is the line itself.